# Outputting temporary feature layer from geoprocessing script tool to current map (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, python-script-tool

This is my first time attempting to create a script tool. I have gotten my script to work when running it in the Python window in ArcGIS Pro, however running from the script tool is slightly different.

Explanation of purpose: We have a dataset detailing crimes. One field called "Label" is the general description (theft, assault, arcson, etc.). There is a secondary field in the dataset called "description" that describes the offense in more detail (assault with a deadly weapon, misdemeanor assault, etc.). The goal is to take main dataset, and explode it into separate feature layers, one feature layer for each unique value in the "label" field. So a feature class for assault, a feature class for arson, etc. These feature classes will be symbolized by unique values for each of the more detailed offenses.

This dataset changes, and there are not always the same number of unique values in the monthly report, so it needs to be flexible in how many output feature layers are created. When I run the script with the parameters set correctly in the Python window, the feature layers are automatically added to the map document. However when I run this from the geoprocessing script tool, it runs successfully, but no output is added.

```
import os
import arcpy

# Set environment
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


proProject = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = proProject.listMaps("Map")[0]

# Get parameters
Input_FeatureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
input_Field1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
input_Field2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# Building unique values list...
arcpy.AddMessage("Building unique values list...")
valueList = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Input_FeatureClass, [input_Field1]) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    l = list(row)
    valueList.append(l[0])
uniqueValues = list(set(valueList))

# Creating Feature Layers...
arcpy.AddMessage("Creating Feature Layers...")
for value in uniqueValues:
  arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(Input_FeatureClass, str(value),  str(input_Field1) + " = '" + str(value) + "'")
```

Comment: Try specifying a [multi-value output parameter](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm) when setting up your script tool, then [`arcpy.SetParameter(parameter_number, list_of_layers)`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/setparameter.htm).

Comment: You could also try arcpy.mp.addLayer in your final loop https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm